# Register user in Django REST framework and set group for user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

My user class is:

```
class UserProfile(User):
    sex = models.SmallIntegerField(verbose_name=_(u'sex'), choices=SEX_TYPES, default=1)
    .
    .
```

UserProfileSerializer:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     groups = GroupSerializer()

     class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username','email','groups')
```

Api view that allow users to register is:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def create_user(request):
      serialized = ProfileSerializer(data=request.DATA)
      if serialized.is_valid():
          created_user = UserProfile.objects.create_user(
              serialized.init_data['email'],
              serialized.init_data['username'],
              serialized.init_data['password'],
          )
          # here I want assign a group for user or anything else
          created_user.groups = "users"
          created_user.save()

          return Response(serialized.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
      else:
          return Response(serialized._errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

with this test:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
{
"username":  "aaa",
"email": "aa@aaa.com" ,
"password":  "111111"
}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/register/
```

There is always error with groups.`{"groups": ["This field is required."]}`

How can I assign a group for user or anything else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have *users* group created, then you do the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

users_group = Group.objects.get(name='users')

created_user.groups = [users_group]
# or instead:
# created_user.groups.add(users_group)
```

Reference:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization

Comment: thanks, I have solved this problem by your anwser and also removing "groups" from fileds in serializer