# How to register users using django-rest-framework and angularJS?

Tags: django, angularjs, rest, django-rest-framework, django-registration

I have a project where am developing a `Django` single page web app using angularJS and now, All calls between the front and back end should be done via `Django-REST.`
Am now doing the registration and I cant seem to figure out exactly what should be done 
 
I saw [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740254/register-user-in-django-rest-framework-and-set-group-for-user) and I was wondering when I fill the sign up form in the front end, how will it be send using rest and save the user. Any help, links on how to go about it will be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You create a service `myService` that will give you `$resource(yourEndpointUrlForUsers)` and then save the data using `myService.save(dataFromForm)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this django app - https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser.

And normal http requests from the fronted controllers to the urls in this app will work.